# When/Why should I use Firebase @Exclude annotation on methods

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

From [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Exclude) I know that we should use this annotation to exclude fields from being saved on firebase. That much I know

But from [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/database/Exclude.java) We can see that this annotation was made so it can be used on methods as well ! As seen on several [examples](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.google.firebase.database.Exclude) But why should I @Exclude a method? And what would happen if I doesn't @Exclude a method? since what are being saved are only fields, I don't know when/why should I use this annotation on methods.

## Edit

As you guys asked this is an example, posted on the link above, when in a firebase project, the firebase team uses @Exclude in a method that is neither a getter or a setter

```
@Exclude
public Map<String, Object> toMap() {
    HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
    result.put("id", id);
    result.put("fullName",fullName);
    result.put("birthDate",birthDate);
    result.put("birthYear", birthYear);
    result.put("height",height);
    result.put("aboutMe",aboutMe);
    result.put("userLocation",userLocation);
    result.put("jobPosition",jobPosition);
    result.put("companyName",companyName);
    result.put("companyLocation",companyLocation);
    result.put("jobStartDate",jobStartDate);
    result.put("homeEmail",homeEmail);
    result.put("homePhone",homePhone);
    result.put("workEmail",workEmail);
    result.put("workPhone",workPhone);
    result.put("facebookName",facebookName);
    result.put("facebookLink",facebookLink);
    result.put("instaName",instaName);
    result.put("instaLink",instaLink);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You use @Exclude on fields if they are public, and you access their values directly.  For example:

```
public class Pojo {
    public String name;
    @Exclude
    public int age;
}
```

You use @Exclude on getter and setter methods when the underlying field is private and all access must go through those accessors.  For example:

```
public class Pojo {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Exclude
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
}
```

The Firebase SDK can discover and use both kinds.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But why there are firebase examples that exclude methods like 'public Map<String, Object> toMap()'? if this kind of method does not access any private fields?

Comment: I don't know of any examples like that.  Consider trying to contact them directly, or give feedback via whatever mechanism they might provide.

Comment: The firebase FAQ(https://firebase.google.com/support/faq/) was the one that suggested that I should create a stackoverflow question with the tag firebase :)

Comment: I can't really help you unless you direct me to the actual code sample.

Comment: @DougStevenson Is it the same thing in Cloud Firestore?

Comment: @IoanaP. Firestore has its own Exclude annotation that does the same thing.

Comment: @DougStevenson Even if I use on the field or only if I use on the getter? Thanks for your response.

Comment: Use the pattern I've shown in my answer - either private members with accessors, or public fields with no accessors.  You shouldn't combine them.